# Return an old view of pipelines in Azure DevOps Server (TFS)

Tags: tfs, azure-devops, azure-devops-pipelines

I'm using Azure DevOps version Dev18.M170.8. In this version running a pipeline is really unsuitable: I have to make 2x more clicks (so, more time is spend).
Is there any way to return an old interface?
Also, I would like to return an old representation of pipeline list.

[image: New Run pipeline view]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is no option to switch to the old interface. And in old interface, you also need to make 2x clicks when you queue a new build:

[image]

If you don't want to queue builds manually, you could set CI trigger for the pipeline. In this way, when you save the pipeline, a build will be triggered automatically, and you don't need to make more clicks.

Comment: Have you checked my reply? Is it helpful?

Comment: Too sad to know that :(
Thank you! @cece-dong-msft